# Office 365 mailbox quota doesn't match license

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing, mailbox, quota

In Office 365, 9 of ~130 user accounts are assigned the license Office 365 Enterprise E3 which, according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#StorageLimits, should assign storage quotas of 100 GB to the corresponding user mailboxes but is actually assigning storage quota of 2 GB.

I couldn't find anything relevant online, hence this post.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by manually setting the quotas using Exchange Online PowerShell command `Set-Mailbox <UPN> -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota 100GB -ProhibitSendQuota 100GB -IssueWarningQuota 98GB`.

On a related note, user mailboxes affected and unaffected by this problem both had `UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults: False` so that seems to be normal.